# Save program state in chrome extension between uses

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that does spell check. I want to implement the feature to 'add a word to dictionary' but I read that chrome extension api does not allow  reading and writing to disk.

currently my dictionary is an array of strings:

```
var dictionary = ["google", "apache", "microsoft"];
```

My question is this:
How should I properly store my dictionary? And how can I change its content during run time for the 'add to dictionary feature'?

Comment: I read that chrome extensions can store data. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Josh mentioned, use the chrome storage API.
For example *chrome.storage.sync.set()* and *chrome.storage.sync.get()* automatically syncs the saved data between the different devices the user uses - it's very nice both for developers and users.

[developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage)

Comment: ok cool it worked; now is there a way to manually edit the data if we are dealing with a content script?

Comment: the above link is broken.
this is the new address: 

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Answer (score 1):

You may use local [storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) of the browser. However if you want to be really flexible you may use nodejs and sockets. That's how I made [my extension](https://github.com/krasimir/auxilio). I used nodejs, which has an access to the user's disk and sockets to communicate with the node app. The only one problem is that the user should install the module.